# A notion of iterated consistency axioms

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, ordinals, meta-math

Let $T$ be some theory (such as Peano Arithmetic or ZFC) capable of expressing arithmetic. We define $T_k$ for some $k$ as $T+\forall x<k.\text{Con}(T_x)$ (call that last axiom $\text{Con}_k(T)).$

Now if, $T$ is also capable of expressing ordinal arithmetic, we can expand this to all ordinal numbers. (Even if it can't, you can create an axiom for each $x$ under $k$, splitting $\text{Con}_k(T)$ into $|k|$ statements. (This won't be a nice theory though unless $k$ is a [recursive ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_ordinal).))

Here's an interesting lemma. If the provable arithmetical statements of $T$ are true in the standard model of natural numbers, then so is every $T_k$. To prove this, assume that all $T_x$ are true. Then $T_x$ are all consistient, since if otherwise, they would prove $0=1$, which is false. This means that $\text{Con}_k(T)$ is true, and so $T_k$ is as well. By transfinite induction, this means $T_k$ is true for all $k$.

This means for example, if we trust $ZFC$, we should trust $ZFC_k$ for all $k$ as well.

Is there a name for this notion of iterated consistency? Any references?

Comment: I've always seen it called iterated consistency.  They're closely related to "reflection principles", and just about everything on the subject can be found by using a search engine with one or the other of those terms.

Comment: @Henry what do you know. My term coincided with the actual term.

Comment: Turing worked on this in his PhD thesis. I think Feferman also worked on this. Torkel Franzen wrote a book about this called 'Inexhaustibility: A Non-Exhaustive Treatment.'.

Comment: This notion is cool, but I'm confused about something. What about $\mathrm{ZFC}_\omega$? It seems that it proves its own consistency by the compactness theorem (I mean, if it's inconsistent, then $\mathrm{ZFC}_n$ is inconsistent for some $n$, which contradicts $\mathrm{ZFC}_{n+1}$...). But it can't, because of the second incompleteness theorem... So what am I not seeing?

Comment: @Cronus you can't quite apply compactness. For example, if $T$ has an axiom saying that $T_\omega$ is false, then $T_n$ will be consistent until $n=\omega$.

Comment: It is definitely possible that $\mathrm{ZFC}_n$ is inconsistent for some $n$. But what if it's not? Or are you saying I just proved it is? (I guess you probably don't; it'd be pretty sad if I did!)

Comment: @Cronus well, it probably is consistent. It is if Kelly Morse set theory is: http://jdh.hamkins.org/km-implies-conzfc/

Comment: So what's wrong with my "proof" of inconsistency?

Comment: The "proof" is this: Assume $\mathrm{ZFC}_\omega+\mathrm{Incon}(\mathrm{ZFC}_\omega)$. Then by compactness there is $n$ such that $\mathrm{ZFC}_n$ is inconsistent. This contradicts $\mathrm{ZFC}_{n+1}$, which is in $\mathrm{ZFC}_\omega$. Thus, $\mathrm{ZFC}_\omega$ proves $\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC}_\omega)$. So, by the second incompleteness theorem, $\mathrm{ZFC}_\omega$ is inconsistent. Surely this "proof" is wrong?

Comment: @Cronus compactness only applies to an infinite sequence of separate axioms, not universal quantifiers. For example, even though every instance of $\forall n. x > n$ can be satisfied, adopting that as an axiom would be inconsistent, since then $x>x$.

Comment: But there are nonstandard models of the natural numbers in which for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (in the metatheory $\mathrm{ZFC}$) there is an element $x$ in the model such that $x\neq 1+...+1$ (where we have $n$ ones). So I don't exactly understand what you're saying. I mean, compactness holds for all sets of axioms...

Comment: @Cronus yes, but even in a nonstandard model, there is no $x>x$. By compactness, we know that the theory $ZFC + ZFC_1 + ZFC_2 + \dots$ is consistent as separate axioms, but we can not conclude that $\forall n. ZFC_n$ is consistent on that grounds, since then our proofs can use infinitely many of the axioms.

Comment: I don't think I understand... Assume $\mathrm{ZFC}_\omega$ and assume by contradiction it is inconsistent. Then, by compactness, a finite subset $\Lambda=\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m\}$ of it is inconsistent. For each $i=1,..,m$ we know $\lambda_i\in\mathrm{ZFC}_\omega=\bigcup\mathrm{ZFC}_n$, so for each such $i$ there is some $n_i$ such that $\lambda_i\in\mathrm{ZFC}_{n_i}$. Let $N=\max_{i=1,..,m}\{n_i\}$. Then $\mathrm{ZFC}_N$ contains $\Lambda=\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m\}$, and hence is inconsistent. This contradicts $\mathrm{ZFC}_{N+1}$, which is in $\mathrm{ZFC}_\omega$.

Comment: So $\mathrm{ZFC}_\omega$ proves its own consistency. Where did I use compactness wrong?

Comment: @Cronus The statement "For all $n$, ZFC$_\omega$ proves "$Con(ZFC_n)$"" doesn't imply the statement "ZFC$_\omega$ proves "$\forall nCon(ZFC_n)$."" (Similarly, supposing ZFC is consistent we have "For each $n$, ZFC proves that $n$ isn't the Godel number of a proof of inconsistency in ZFC" but clearly we don't have "ZFC proves that each $n$ isn't ...".) Think of it this way: in any proof from ZFC$_\omega$, we can only use finitely many axioms; these finitely many axioms can only reach finitely high up the ZFC$_n$-hierarchy, so we can never actually bring the full power we expect into play.

Comment: Another example of this phenomenon is [the reflection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle#In_ZFC).

Comment: Thank you! It was actually explained to me since then. Seems like such a silly question of me now ;) This shift of the quantifiers can be so confusing... $ZFC_\omega$ has each $Con(ZFC_n)$, but he doesn't know it!

Comment: Late comment, but see [this blog post on what happens if you have iterated consistency or even iterated reflection](https://xorshammer.com/2009/03/23/what-happens-when-you-iterate-godels-theorem).